# How to encode a jpeg as an IncomingFrame or i420format frame while using ViEExternalCapture?

Tags: android, jpeg, webrtc

I am trying to send a stream of static JPEG images instead of video, by adapting the webrtc demo android app (available [here](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fwebrtc%2Fvideo_engine%2Ftest%2Fandroid)).

I'm using the ViEExternalCapture class in the [VIECapture api](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/webrtc-internals/viecapture#TOC-Class-ViEExternalCapture).

The methods require a video frame and I don't know how to convert the jpeg to match the arguments of either functions.

```
 virtual int IncomingFrame(unsigned char* videoFrame,

                          unsigned int videoFrameLength,

                          unsigned short width, unsigned short height,

                          RawVideoType videoType,

                          unsigned long long captureTime = 0);

virtual int IncomingFrameI420(const ViEVideoFrameI420& video_frame,

                                            unsigned long long captureTime = 0) = 0;
```

I have looked into Media Codec Api and the Bitmap Factory but couldn't find an answer.

(apologies for not providing more links, but it won't let me as I am new here.)

Comment: Let me know if you figure it out - as I am trying to do the same thing on Android ;)  the I420Frame Java object is really not something Android deals with native.